# how to pass expect.toMatchObject() with Date as one of the expected property value using jest?

Tags: datetime, testing

I have an express API endpoint which returns an object and on that object there is a property(property3 in our example below) which has a date as it's value.

For e.g

```
  res.body = {
       "property1": "value1"
       "property2": "value2"
       "property3": new Date()
    }
```

I am performing test on this endpoint using jest and supertest.

Since date.now() !== date.now(), how will i pass

`expect(res.body).toMatchObject(<expectedObject>)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `expect.objectContaining` which matches subset properties only. Above example can write as following:

```js
expect(res.body).toMatchObject(expect.objectContaining({
  "property1": "value1"
  "property2": "value2"
}))
```